# How to merge/condense two tables that contain random NA values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 =  data.frame(Experiment = "exp",
                  Variable = ".13",
                  Genename = "ENSG00003",
                  Index = 1,
                  Score1 = NA,
                  Score2 = 1,
                  Score3 = 1:2
                  )

df2 =  data.frame(Experiment = "exp",
                  Variable = ".13",
                  Genename = "ENSG00003",
                  Index = NA,
                  Score1 = 1,
                  Score2 = NA,
                  Score3 = 1:2
                  )
```

I want to merge them together so that the NA values in the first dataframe are replaced if there is a non NA value in the second. It is very important that no non-NA value is ever overwritten, and ideally I would like to save any df2 value that would otherwise overlap a non-NA value in df1 in a new column, although this should absolutely never occur normally and I would really rather be alerted if it does occur.

I've tried:

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = names(df1), by.y = names(df2), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)

merge(x = df1, y = df2, by.x = c("Experiment", "Variable", "Index", "Genename"), by.y = c("Experiment", "Variable", "Index", "Genename"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = TRUE)

aggregate(. ~ Genename, data = merge(df1, df2, all= TRUE), na.action = na.pass, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

dplyr::full_join(x = df1, y = df2, by = c("Experiment", "Variable", "Genename"))

data %>% mutate(mycol = coalesce(x,y,z)) %>% select(a, mycol)

coalesce(df1, df2)
```

And furthermore played around with various arguments for the above, omitted here for brevity. I just can't seem to find a simple way to do what I need to do. I simply want to merge two dataframes non-destructively, and omit NA values from that 'non-destructive' clause.

Comment: What is wrong with the `coalesce(df1, df2)` or `coalesce(df2, df1)` ? They looked me just fine. What is your expected output?

Comment: I need the merge to be able to handle unexpected columns in df2, and I am worried that coalescing by column might result in columns collapsing out of sync with one another.

Answer (score 0):

Do a full join first and then use `coalesce()` inside a `mutate()`. Note that in your example the join columns are not unique and, therefore, in the output each row is duplicated. You still have to clean up those duplicates.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = c("Experiment", "Variable", "Genename")) %>% 
  mutate(
    Index = coalesce(Index.x, Index.y),
    Score1 = coalesce(Score1.x, Score1.y),
    Score2 = coalesce(Score2.x, Score2.y),
    Score3 = coalesce(Score3.x, Score3.y),
  ) %>% 
  select(-ends_with(".x"), -ends_with(".y"))
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to mention that I need to do it as a whole dataframe because I need the merge to be able to handle unexpected columns in df2, and I am worried that coalescing by column might result in columns collapsing out of sync with one another.